# Gazebo 2.2.6 not starting

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm getting the following error whenever I want to start Gazebo. Any ideas in how to solve it?

> andrestoga@andrestoga-RoboLab:~/ros_Map_Merging$
> gazebo Gazebo multi-robot simulator,
> version 2.2.6 Copyright (C) 2012-2014
> Open Source Robotics Foundation.
> Released under the Apache 2 License.
> http://gazebosim.org
>
> Msg Waiting for master Gazebo
> multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.6
> Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source
> Robotics Foundation. Released under
> the Apache 2 License.
> http://gazebosim.org
>
> Msg Waiting for master Msg Connected
> to gazebo master @
> ttp://127.0.0.1:11345 32mMsg Connected
> to gazebo master @
> http://127.0.0.1:11345 [1;mMsgMsg
> Publicized address: Publicized
> address: 169.236.180.44169.236.180.44
>
> X Error of failed request:  BadValue
> (integer parameter out of range for
> operation)   Major opcode of failed
> request:  154 (GLX)   Minor opcode of
> failed request:  3
> (X_GLXCreateContext)   Value in failed
> request:  0x0   Serial number of
> failed request:  24   Current serial
> number in output stream:  25

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14878/gazebo-2.2.6-not-starting/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2914/andrestoga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It has the graphic driver installed. Actually, I was using Gazebo before that error occurred. I just restarted my computer and it works again.

---

Originally posted by [andrestoga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2914/andrestoga/) with karma: 20 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0